# Editing Grub - "no such file or directory found"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, grub

I had installed reinstalled windows and ubuntu various times.

Now Everything is set and I want to edit grub to set windows 7 as my default os

when I run this command

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

I get an error that No such file or Directory found`

then I tried this

```
sudo grub
find /boot/grub/stage1
```

I get an error No File found. Can anybody help me how can I change my default os?

// Edited

```
ls -a /boot/grub
```

[image: ls -a /boot/grub]

Comment: what does "ls -a /boot/grub" say?

Comment: Please check the editted part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then edit the line -
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
to
GRUB_DEFAULT=4  (assuming you have only 2 os 1 ubuntu another xp / vista / 7)

save the file, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've installed GRUB2, there where several changes to it. For global options please see the `/boot/grub/grub.env` and edit this one, for changing the boot order, reorder the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` (reorder them by replacing the leading numbers in the filename).

Comment: can you guide me what should I do I am unable to understand

Comment: You need to be absolutely sure what you're doing when you change an important file like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file containing the menu is now `grub.cfg`

When I changed it, I just edited it (and ignored the message NOT to do so).

I can see it in the listing you provided. I think you want to put the entry for Windows 7 *first* in the menu.

I hesitate to say more, because I don't have a Windows entry in my grub.cfg, and it would be dangerous for me to speculate on what to do next.